# how to select tables with scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping a page which contains tables, I can extract the  links I'm interested in this way:

```
 response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]/tr/td[1]/a/@href').extract()
```

Now, there are 3 or more tables, if I write this way:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table/tr/td[1]/a/@href').extract()
```

I get the data of all the tables, but if I only want n tables, there a way to get it without use n expresions, something
like this:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1:n]/tr/td[1]/a/@href').extract()
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `n` is an integer, you can use `position()` within your `XPath` query as follows:

```
'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[position() <= {}]/tr/td[1]/a/@href'.format(str(n))
```

This will select the data from the first `n` tables as required.

Alternatively, you can use a loop as follows:

```
for i in range(5):
    response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[{}]/tr/td[1]/a/@href'.format(str(i))).extract()
```

Comment: Great, where can I see the documentation of that function?

Answer (score 1):

```
'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[position()<n]/tr/td[1]/a/@href'
```